# Cannot invoke 'indexOf' with an argument list of type '(ChecklistItem)'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

When I am writing code for finding an item from the array with the use of indexOf it shows me the above stated error.
Here is my code:-

```
func addItemViewController(controller: AddItemViewController, didFinishEditingItem item: ChecklistItem)
{
    if let index = items.indexOf(item)
    {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        {
            configureTextForCell(cell, withChecklistItem: item)
        }
    }
```

Comment: would be nice if you can put the citation of the code, which I believe it is the chapter 2 of the book **iOS apprentice**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In order to use `indexOf` the `ChecklistItem` must adopt [Equatable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/index.html). Only by adopting this protocol the list can compare an item with other items to find the desired index

Answer (score 14):

`indexOf` can only be applied to Collections of `Equatable` types, your `ChecklistItem` doesn't conform to `Equatable` protocol (have an `==` operator).

To be able to use `indexOf` add this to the file containing `ChecklistItem` class in the global scope :

```
func ==(lhs: ChecklistItem, rhs: ChecklistItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs
}

Swift3: 
public static func ==(lhs: Place, rhs: Place) -> Bool {
        return lhs === rhs
    }
```

Please note it will make comparison by comparing instances addresses in memory. You may want to check equality by comparing members of the class instead.

Comment: also remember to make your class conform to `Equatable` by adding it to the class definition.

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 4 and Swift 3**, update your Data Model to conform to "Equatable" protocol, and implement the lhs=rhs method , only then you can use ".index(of:...)", because you are comparing your custom object

```
Eg:
class Photo : Equatable{
    var imageURL: URL?
    init(imageURL: URL){
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }

    static func == (lhs: Photo, rhs: Photo) -> Bool{
        return lhs.imageURL == rhs.imageURL
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let index = self.photos.index(of: aPhoto)
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question already has an accepted answer, but I found another case that will cause this error so it might help someone else. I'm using Swift 3.

If you create a collection and allow the type to be inferred you may also see this error.

Example:

```
// UITextfield conforms to the 'Equatable' protocol, but if you create an
// array of UITextfields and leave the explicit type off you will
// also see this error when trying to find the index as below
let fields = [
        tf_username,
        tf_email,
        tf_firstname,
        tf_lastname,
        tf_password,
        tf_password2
    ]

// you will see the error here
let index = fields.index(of: textField)

// to fix this issue update your array declaration with an explicit type
let fields:[UITextField] = [
    // fields here
]
```

Answer (score 3):

The possible reason is you didn't tell the **ChecklistItem** type that it is equatable, maybe you forgot to mention **ChecklistItem** class is inherited from **NSObject**.

```
import Foundation

class ChecklistItem: NSObject {
  var text = ""
  var checked = false

  func toggleChecked() {
    checked = !checked
  }
}
```

**NSObject** adopts or conforms to the equatable protocol

Comment: inheriting from NSObject is garbage and should be avoided in swift